# SQL: easy way to cast/parse a varchar to an int or Zero (not NULL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to cast a varchar value of about 11 or 12 characters into an integer value and do some math with it.

**If parsing the varchar is not possible, the return value should be 0 (zero) in ANY case.** Not null, not an error.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) -- NULL
SELECT CAST('' AS INT)   -- 0
SELECT CAST('42' AS INT) -- 42
SELECT CAST('abc' AS INT) -- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type int.

SELECT TRY_PARSE(NULL AS INT) -- Argument data type NULL is invalid for argument 1 of parse function.
SELECT TRY_PARSE('' AS INT)   -- 0
SELECT TRY_PARSE('42' AS INT) -- 42
SELECT TRY_PARSE('abc' AS INT) -- NULL

SELECT TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, '0') AS INT) -- 0
SELECT TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, '') AS INT)   -- NULL
SELECT TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, '42') AS INT) -- 42
SELECT TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, 'abc') AS INT) -- NULL
```

The expected output would be

```
'0' --> 0
'' --> 0
'42' --> 0 42
'abc' --> 0
```

This works, but hey, this is reeeealy ugly:

```
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, '0') AS INT), 0) -- 0
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, '') AS INT), 0) -- 0 
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, '42') AS INT), 0) -- 42 
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(ISNULL(NULL, 'abc') AS INT), 0) -- 0
```

**Is there a simple way without using exceeding numbers of wrapped method calls?**

*Note: [SQL Server cast varchar to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881683/sql-server-cast-varchar-to-int) does not take into account the various error situations*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `try_convert()` with `coalesce()` function to avoid error message

```
select coalesce(try_convert(int, null), 0) -- 0   
select coalesce(try_convert(int, ''), 0) -- 0   
select coalesce(try_convert(int, '42'), 0) -- 42   
select coalesce(try_convert(int, 'abs'), 0) -- 0
```

Comment: Works well for me, also the zero case. I wonder what the coalesce doese instead of isnull. Is there a difference to know of.

Comment: @Marcel... `coalesce()` is ANSI SQL Standard function while `isnull()` is specific to only SQL Server. You could look at some [little variations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce/).

Answer (score 1):

No need for the two ISNULL()'s

```
SELECT isnull(try_convert(int,null),0)   -- 0
SELECT isnull(try_convert(int,'0'),0)    -- 0
SELECT isnull(try_convert(int,''),0)     -- 0
SELECT isnull(try_convert(int,'42'),0)   -- 42
SELECT isnull(try_convert(int,'abc'),0)  -- 0
```

Comment: Works well for me.